# call a script file from one docker container to another container using --link container

Tags: linux, docker, containers, tensorflow, syntaxnet

I have created a container with a name of "tensorflow-syntaxnet_container" using docker command `docker run -d -name tensorflow_syntaxnet_container syntaxnet_image` and the other container "python_flask" with linking the tensorflow-syntaxnet_container using docker command `docker run -d -p 0.0.0.0:5001:5001 --link tensorflow-syntaxnet_container:syntaxnet -name python_flask  python_image:latest` and both the containers are create successfully and its working as expected individually.

Also verified that python_flask container lined with syntaxnet container as cat /etc/hosts results `172.17.0.27     syntaxnet e002ab9f43a7 tensorflow-syntaxnet_container` which is container ip of syntaxnet container.

i need call a script file demo.sh and need to access output file in `connect with tensorflow-syntaxnet_container` from my python flask application located at `python_flask container`

i could not find any mount directory or folder of linked container tensorflow-syntaxnet_container

Could any one can help me out how to call the script file and access all file from one container to another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check it here [Docker Link Docks](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/)
and here [Docker Volume Docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#creating-and-mounting-a-data-volume-container)

With `--link` you only can link network interfaces of container. If you want to share filesystem, you will, probably, need `--volumes-from`.

```
docker create -v /path/to/script/dir --name scriptstore image1:name
docker run -d --volumes-from scriptstore --name runner image2:name bash /path/to/script/dir/scriptname.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

Linking two containers enables network communication. What you want are volumes: https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#/creating-and-mounting-a-data-volume-container